# React with Formik problem with onSubmit not working until the button is clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, formik

I'm new to React. I've done some research on this site and elsewhere and am not seeing a solution for this particular problem, although I've seen some that were similar. The app uses formik's onSubmit to send data from the form to a custom hook which returns the state in the form of response.type and response.message. I encounter this error on the first button click, but not on subsequent clicks:

Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: response is null

Below is a simplified representation:

```
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      // submit is a call to a custom hook which returns reponse.type and response.message
      // on the second and subsequent clicks of the submit button, but not first
      submit(console.log('submitted'), values)
      console.log(response.type, response.message)
      formik.resetForm();
    },
```

I realize that by the time console.log(response.type, response.message) are called the state has not had a chance to be updated and I have tried several different async/await methods, but cannot seem to get it to work on first click of the submit button. It works as expected on the second click and subsequent clicks.